# excluding an object file from linkage

Tags: c++, linker, makefile

I need to link an executable on Linux with all object files in some folder besides one of the files. I see that in makefile I can use wildcards to specify linkage with all obj files without specifying the full list of files - http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_4.html#SEC21

In addition to this I'm looking for a way to exclude a specific object file from linkage.
Is there a way to achieve this?

I'm trying to avoid the need to maintain a list of many dozens of object files in makefiles. I specifically need to link with object files and linking them into a library isn't an option.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks. I've missed that post.

Answer (score 1):

> I see that in makefile I can use wildcards to specify linkage with all obj files without specifying the full list of files

Yes: GNU make allows you to do this. Generally that is a *really bad idea*: your executable will build fine one day, and will fail the next because there is some "stray" object that got deposited there.

> I'm looking for a way to exclude a specific object file from linkage

GNU make also has `filter-out` function that allows you do precisely what you want. Documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html).